# Sorting sub-queries in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, subquery, row-number

I've been trying to a query working in SQL 2012 which I'm almost certain I am over complicating

I have a table which stores an order number, item numbers (multiple per order), status codes (multiple per item) and a timestamp

So basically something like this

```
Order Item Status
1     1    1
1     1    2

2     1    1
2     1    2
2     1    3

3     1    3
3     2    1
3     2    2
```

Within my query (using this table as the example), I need see the following 1 entry for each line and item but only showing the highest available status... BUT not if the status is 3

So in this case, I'd want to see

```
Order Item Status
1     1    2
3     2    2
```

The issue I had is that the query itself works... but it returns the FIRST status code it finds. Not the highest one. So I end up with

```
Order Item Status
1     1    1  
3     2    1
```

Here's the full expanded code snippet

```
with summary as (
select a.order_no as order_no, a.item_no as item_no, a.timestamp as timestamp, 
max(a.status_code) as status_code, row_number() over (partition by order_no
order by item_no asc) as rn
from db.ordhist a
where a.order_no > 120400000 and a.order_no < 120800000
and a.timestamp < Dateadd(DD,-3,GETDATE() )
and a.status_code >= 133
and not exists (
select b.order_no, b.item_no
from db.ordhist b
where b.status_code in (137,170,201,999)
and b.order_no = a.order_no
and b.item_no = a.item_no)
and not exists (
select c.order_no
from db.ordhist c
where c.status_code = 6
and c.order_no = a.order_no)
group by a.order_no, a.item_no, a.timestamp)
select * from summary where rn = 1
```

Comment: show also the desired output for sample data, the description of what you want is a little ambiguous

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need `ROW_NUMBER` just use a `GROUP BY` with `HAVING MAX([Status])<>3`:

```
    SELECT  [Order],[Item],MAX([Status])
    FROM Table_Name
    GROUP BY [Order],[Item]
    HAVING MAX([Status])<>3
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I may have answered my own question.... by removing the grouping within the "summary" and doing grouping in the final results query instead

```
-- Produced (or higher) but not Delivery Noted --
with summary as (
select a.order_no as order_no, a.item_no as item_no, a.timestamp as timestamp, a.status_code as status_code
from db.ordhist a
where a.order_no > 120400000 and a.order_no < 120800000
and a.timestamp < Dateadd(DD,-3,GETDATE() )
and a.status_code >= 133
and not exists (
select b.order_no, b.item_no
from db.ordhist b
where b.status_code in (137,170,201,999)
and b.order_no = a.order_no
and b.item_no = a.item_no)
and not exists (
select c.order_no
from db.ordhist c
where c.status_code = 6
and c.order_no = a.order_no))
select order_no, item_no, timestamp, max(status_code) from summary 
group by order_no, item_no, timestamp
order by status_code
```